# Facing problem in setting up libpng

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, libpng

What I'm trying to do is to use libpng in my opengl project to load sprites using xcode.
I've downloaded the package of libpng from internet and added its source to my project but when I try to build, it gives this error:
"Command Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1"
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time. But the problem was "I missed to add libz.dylib framework to my project".

Hope it may help someone having the same problem like me.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously don't have the `gcc-4.2` executable residing in the `Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/` directory. Tune your IDE directories to point to the correct locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this libpng error while debugging your app on the device, In Xcode 4 goto “Build Settings” search for PNG in the search box and make "compress PNG files" to 'No', which makes PNG compression to turn off.

[image]